# laravel [InvalidArgumentException] Script "post-install-cmd" is not defined in this package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.5 was released yesterday and I am trying to install, but i have a problem after installing the update. The output:

```
[InvalidArgumentException] Script "post-install-cmd" is not defined in this package"
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Do `composer global update` before `laravel new <project-name>` and you'll be alright. It will update your laravel installer to its latest version to support Laravel 5.5 LTS.

see [comment](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/4399#issuecomment-326191024) in [Fixed composer's invalid argument exception](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/4399)